# Which is the best way to track email open rates with Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Would anyone suggest best way to tracks email open rates with Google Analytics?

I used this html tag

```
<img src="http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=4.8.6&utmn=1214284135&utmhn=www.sample-site.ph&utmt=event&utme=open-basic-plus-campaign&utmcs=utf-8&utmul=en&utmje=1&utmfl=10.1%20r102&utmdt=Basic Plus Campaign&utmr=0&utmp=Basic Plus Campaign&utmac=UA-GANUMBER-1" />
```

but nothing happen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try replace UA-GANUMBER-1 with your own analytics ID